# Performance issue of having multiple grids on same page querying huge table

Tags: performance, gridview, multiple-instances, page-load-time

I need some design advise here.  i have a big table and it stores records of 4 different status(for example A,B,C & D).  The requirement is in UI, these records needs tobe shown in 4 different grids based on the status.

so i have written a single stored procedure which takes status as input and returns a dataset. And on page load am calling this SP is called 4 times with different status and then results are bound to gridview.  Everything works fine.

the problem is, since the table is a huge table, it takes lot of time to load the page.

Note : the requirement is to show all 4 grids so that user can compare the data in those grids.

I have already added indexes to this table, but still no use.

What is the best design to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the SP to return 4 result sets instead of one.

Call the new SP once.

Return back less results in each result set, and instead introduce paging.

Comment: Also we cannot return them as 4 datasets because, when the user clicks on a column of a individual grid to sort, only that grid needs to be sorted.  in such case, it makes call to DB for getting the sorted data.  so in such case, i am not sure if performance will be better if we return all 4 datasets when we want to sort just one grid.

Comment: i have implemented paging. so each grid shows 10 rows.  Note : the table will have more than 100,000 rows.